# Wrong answer on "I can guess the data structure!"

Tags: python, algorithm, queue, stack, priority-queue

I'm trying to solve the [I can guess the data structure!](https://open.kattis.com/problems/guessthedatastructure) problem but my script is not approved by kattis. The kattis test returns "wrong answer" on the second test. Does anyone know what might be wrong with the algorithm?

```
import sys


def determine_data_structure():
    hand = []
    is_stack = True
    is_queue = True
    is_priority_queue = True
    impossible = False
    num_operations = None

    for line in sys.stdin:
        if " " not in line:
            num_operations = int(line)
        else:
            line_values = line.split(" ")
            operation = int(line_values[0])
            value = int(line_values[1])
            if operation == 1:
                # Take a value from the bag
                hand.append(value)
            elif operation == 2 and value in hand:
                # Check if the value matches the expected value for each data structure
                if value in hand:
                    if is_stack and value != hand[-1]:
                        is_stack = False
                    if is_queue and value != hand[0]:
                        is_queue = False
                    if is_priority_queue and value != max(hand):
                        is_priority_queue = False
                    hand.remove(value)
            elif operation == 2 and value not in hand:
                impossible = True
                is_stack = False
                is_queue = False
                is_priority_queue = False

            num_operations -= 1

        if num_operations == 0:
            if impossible or sum([is_stack, is_queue, is_priority_queue]) == 0:
                print("impossible")
            elif sum([is_stack, is_queue, is_priority_queue]) > 1:
                print("not sure")
            elif is_stack:
                print("stack")
            elif is_queue:
                print("queue")
            elif is_priority_queue:
                print("priority queue")
            is_stack = True
            is_queue = True
            is_priority_queue = True
            impossible = False
            hand.clear()


determine_data_structure()
```

I have tried several different inputs and the program outputs the correct data structure. Kattis is telling me that there are some input that is not generating the right output

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is not guaranteeing that x is unique (look at the bounds for x vs. n). So `hand.remove(value)` may remove the wrong thing.

Example:

```
7
1 1
1 2
1 1
1 1
2 1
2 1
2 2
```

your answer: impossible

I would expect: stack

I think you should actually simulate the candidate structures separately, not in one list.